# debugging angular JS custom directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am totally new to Angualr JS. Is there any way to debug code in custom directives? I don't understand what is going on in some of custom directives at a work project and I think to be able to debug the code would be a good idea to understand what is going on in the code. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any javascript that you can find in your browser's developer tools can typically be debugged.

Comment: open developer console, step into each function and debug it. Minified code is bit difficult to debug. So prefer to run it without minification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it helpful to use plunkr to test directives in isolation with the CSS and JavaScript dependencies included by CDN URLs or their equivalent